# .NET Core missing from Target framework list

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, I'm trying to change the target framework on a unit test project to .NET Core so that I can use xUnit. I don't see it in the list of available frameworks.

In my list of available frameworks, I see:

```
.NET Framework 2.0 -> 4.7.1 and several Unity Frameworks.
```

This is despite the fact that I have .NET Core SDK 2.1.200 (x64), 2.1.202 (x64), and 2.1.500 (x64) installed.

Comment: If it's a project targeting .NET Framework I don't think you get options to change it to .NET Core or .NET Standard because it isn't that simple. You need to either create a new project or manually edit your .csproj file to convert it.

Comment: @Eric: Did you try creating a Visual C#->.NET Core->xUnit Test Project (.NET Core) project?

Comment: The `Target Framework` property shows only supported conversions.  You *can't* change from 4.7.1 to .NET Core just by changing the target framework. The project file format itself is different. There are several articles and duplicate questions that explain how you could convert one format to the other by hand, although the best option is probably to start with a new project and just copy the source files over

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, there are some conversations that don't necessarily cause problems but nonetheless aren't shown.  For example, I just converted a project from .NET Standard 2.0 to .NET Core 3.0 by editing the project file (as Jimmy describes below), and no problems arose.  I gather it's not _guaranteed_ to work, but it can be a lot faster than creating a new project and moving everything over.

Comment: @RyanLundy that doesn't mean the change is supported *by Visual Studio*. In any the question is specifically for changing 4.7.1 to .NET Core 3.0 through the dropdown, something that requires changing the project file to the new format and cleaning up transient package dependencies. That's what the [new try-convert tool](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert) does

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have 2 options, both of which are easy:

## Change your target framework to netcoreapp*

Edit your project file and change

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

(or whichever version of .NET Core you wish to target.  SDK 2.1.500 is netcoreapp2.1 I believe.)

## Use XUnit in a .NET Framework project

Create a .NET Framework class library project and install the `xunit` NuGet package.  Then you can just start using XUnit like normal, and it can reference your web project.

To run test in VS, you'll also need the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package.

Comment: This will only work if the OP already changed the csproj file to use the new format manually.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio only shows supported conversions. Converting from .NET Framework to .NET Core though isn't as simple as changing a version number.

You can use [try-convert](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert) to make the necessary modifications to the project file. Make sure you use `--diff-only` first to inspect the changes.

You should check [Nate McMaster's](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) migration guide and [Additions to the csproj format for .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) to understand the changes.

The tool isn't supported by Microsoft, nor is it guaranteed to perform a 100% conversion.

> This tool is not supported in any way.
>
> **Who is this tool for?**
>
> This tool is for anyone looking to get a little help migrating their projects to .NET Core (or .NET SDK-style projects).
>
> As the name suggests, this tool is not guaranteed to fully convert a project into a 100% working state. The tool is conservative and does as good of a job as it can to ensure that a converted project can still be loaded into Visual Studio and build. However, there are an enormous amount of factors that can result in a project that may not load or build that this tool explicitly does not cover. These include:
>
> - Complex, custom builds that you may have in your solution
> - API usage that is incompatible with .NET Core
> - Unsupported project types (such as Xamarin, WebForms, or WCF projects)
>
> If the bulk of your codebase is generally capable of moving to .NET Core (such as lots of class libraries with no platform-specific code), then this tool should help quite a bit.
>
> **It is highly recommended that you use this tool on a project that is under source control.**

Emphasis mine.

**Why?**

.NET Core and .NET Framework use very different `csproj` formats and handle package references differently, especially transient dependencies, ie packages that are needed by another package.

In .NET Framework `packages.config` contained all packages which means you had no idea which packages were really needed. In .NET Core there's no `packages.config`. The `csproj` files contains `PackageReference` elements only for the top-level dependencies.

In the old `csproj` format, you had to include every single source file explicitly. In the new format, all source files are included automatically, resulting in a file that's *very* easy to edit.

Making those changes isn't trivial. Until recently that was [a manual process](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/). Personally, I just removed everything, copied the minimal XML and added back package references until I got a succesful build. Even then, I had to manually add lines about included/excluded/copty-to-output files. If I had custom build steps with conditions etc, things would be a lot harder.